# Show different layout depending on a condition

Tags: java, android

In my case I have two layout, but I have check the mainactivity's  oncreate, if the file is created then open indexpage, activity_indexpage2.xml, but I can't not print this result to check bug.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        contentfile = read();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(contentfile!=null
    ){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, indexpage.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_indexpage2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
     public String read() throws IOException {

    FileInputStream input = this.openFileInput(File_NAME);
    byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = input.read(temp)) > 0) {
        stringBuffer.append(new String(temp, 0, len));
    }

    input.close();
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreate()` your first statement should be [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(int)) then you need to [request permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for reading external storage then if you have permission granted then check if the file exists or not. Then depending on the condition show your proper layout or navigate to another activity using [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)